# Event not firing after setting OnClientClick in RowDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an Asp.net GridView (populate with a data binding).
One of my columns is a ButtonField (obviously with his own CommandName).

The *GridView_RowCommand* works perfectly, but if i add a *GridView_RowDataBound* (in which I simply add a javascript confirm) the *GridView_RowCommand* event is not fired in the PostBack.

What could be the problem/solution?

Adding code for better understanding:

Aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
    onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MyField1" HeaderText="MyField1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MyField2" HeaderText="MyField2" />
        <asp:ButtonField Text="MyAction" ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="myaction.gif" CommandName="myaction" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

c# code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        (e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1].Controls[0] as ImageButton).OnClientClick = "javascript:return confirm (\"Do action?\");";
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "myaction")
    {
        DoMyAction();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I forgot to tell that my GridView is inside an ajax TabContainer (AjaxControlToolkit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is what is emitted normally for the Image button:

```
<input type="image" src="myaction.gif" alt="MyAction" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','myaction$1')" style="border-width:0px;" />
```

when you set OnClientClick in your code-behind, it will prepend your code but still add the __doPostBack function call, resulting in the following html:

```
<input type="image" src="myaction.gif" alt="MyAction" onclick="javascript:return confirm('Do action?');javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','myaction$1')" style="border-width:0px;" />
```

the onclick event handler will return before it gets a chance to do the postback properly (it will just submit the form).

Doing this:

```
(e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1].Controls[0] as ImageButton).OnClientClick = "if (!confirm('Do action?')) { return false; }";
```

should allow the client-side click event to run the __doPostBack function and raise the RowCommand event server-side as expected when the user clicks OK.

(As a side-note, this is a good example of one of the drawbacks of ASP.NET WebForms - there is a lot of html being generated that you just have no control over. ASP.NET MVC FTW!)

Comment: It worked! Thank you!
I still wonder why "javascript:return confirm (\"Do action?\");" is different from "if (!confirm('Do action?')) { return false; }"

and btw you are right: ASP.NET MVC FTW!

Comment: I try to answer myself.. the working version returns false if I click 'no' but it doesn't return true if I click on 'yes'

Comment: you've got it :) glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance this seems fine. Have you tried running your code outside the TabContainer?

It might get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use sender as argument on `ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink` function so it will create client js event dinamicaly. Bellow the example in `RowDataBound`, where sender is `GridView` (VB).
`YourCommand` will be passed as argument for `RowCommand` event to be raised.

```
e.Row.Cells(columnIndex).Attributes.Add("onclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(sender, "YourCommand$" & e.Row.DataItemIndex))
```